# Can you view the BCD store and determine if the system is using the MBR or GPT?

Tags: mbr, bcd, guid

Can you view the BCD store and determine if the system is using the MBR or GPT partitioning system?

[image]

Comment: The fact it has an EFI partition is everything you need to determine if it's GPT or MBR.  MBR is incompatible with UEFI Mode.  UEFI Mode requires an EFI partition.  If there is an EFI partition it means Windows is installed in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I tell if a Windows system is using MBR or GPT?

Use the following procedure:

> 1. Open an elevated command prompt.
> 2. Type `diskpart` and `list disk` commands into the elevated command prompt one at a time, and press Enter for each command. (see
>    screenshot below)
> 3. Look to see if a Disk # has a * (asterisk) in its GPT column or not.
>
> [image]
>
> If a Disk # has a `*` in its GPT column, then the disk is GPT.
>
> If a Disk # does not have a `*` in its GPT column, then the disk is
> MBR.

Source: [Check if Disk is MBR or GPT in Windows Hardware & Drivers - Windows 10 Forums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/84888-check-if-disk-mbr-gpt-windows.html#option3)

The above also includes a PowerShell script.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This helped a ton!